# Right join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made this query that right joins 2 tables but it doesn't display right, it show all the data without the null camps  from lin_doc what am I doing wrong

My query:

```
select cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, l.id_estab, l.quantidade, (select sum(quantidade) from lin_doc l where l.id_cab_doc = cd.id) as qtd 
from cab_doc cd RIGHT JOIN
     lin_doc l on l.id_cab_doc = cd.id 
where cd.id_tipo_doc = 1
```

output

```
1 /13-12-88/ xxxx /01 /2000 /321
```

and it should appear like this:

```
1 /13-12-88/ xxx /321

null /null /null /01 /2000/ null
```

Comment: Wothout some sample data, it's very hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: The table structure and some sample data that should give the result you're showing.

Comment: After some coffee I re-read the question and figured out a problem. You may want to try the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has a WHERE condition on a column that is possibly NULL due to the RIGHT JOIN.
This will basically make it into an inner join. Move the WHERE condition into the JOIN condition instead and things should work as you expect;

```
SELECT cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, l.id_estab, 
       l.quantidade, 
       (SELECT SUM(quantidade) FROM lin_doc l WHERE l.id_cab_doc = cd.id) AS qtd 
FROM cab_doc cd 
RIGHT JOIN lin_doc l 
  ON l.id_cab_doc = cd.id 
 AND cd.id_tipo_doc = 1
```

Comment: That doesn't look right. His first output, the output that ran based on  the query he quoted means that 'lin_doc l' joined on cd.id. The expected output says it would not join on cd.id therefore would return some records that would be NULL.

Comment: it solves more a less the situation because it now shows some extra null values and some lines like in my first query

Comment: Sure, if by that, you mean you know the RIGHT JOIN is useless and you were lookin for a UNION statement instead. I am willing to bet that nothing will ever join on this suggestion. ;)

Comment: @Fastidious Not sure why you think the right join wouldn't work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9955dc/1

Comment: No, it works for the limited information you have. The fiddle you linked assumes that he has 1 ROW that matches and 2 ROWS that do not match. This is beyond the scope of what he provided. His query and output clearly shows that 1 ROW does match. Then he says it shouldn't, but instead not match and return NULL's in the fields that did not match. This indicates he does not want to JOIN, but likely UNION 2 tables together that do not match (RIGHT JOIN).

Comment: So, I'm saying that RIGHT JOIN is likely never going to match the lin_doc table. Which is returning a result he is expecting. Which is also a bad suggestion to JOIN on a table that will never JOIN if my assumption is right. :D